# Constrain connection/rope/line to avoid stretching

Tags: java, android, algorithm, libgdx, game-physics

We've been developing a game (2d) in which an object can be connected to static points. Each connection (which is a rope in our case) has a fixed length which can be changed (only one at the time). The situation could look like in the attached picture. Now I would like to find out in which direction the object can be moved and how far until some ropes are fully stretched. In other words, I want to find out which rope can be shortened and how much until some ropes are stretching. Thank you for any hints!

[image: Example situation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a circle with radius equals length of the robe around each static point. The area intersecting all circles is the area the object can move. At the border of the area at least one robe is stretched.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your input. I thought the same. So if I want to check if the object can be moved into direction X I just have to find out if the new position exceeds the radius of one of the static points (and its rope), right? But how to find out how far it can be moved into the desired direction? Would it be sufficient to calculate the min exceeding distance?

Comment: You need calculate the intersection of a line in the wanted direction with all circles. The intersection nearest to the origin object is the fares you can get in this direction.

Comment: Thats basically the same isn't it? Assuming the new position of the object is O(x/y) then I have to calculate the distance between the circle and P that would be "distance = sqrt((circle.x-O.x)^2 + (circle.y-O.y)^2) - radius" if it is greater than 0 it cannot be moved, and if it is smaller than 0 then it can be moved "moveDistance = Math.abs(distance)"? (The smallest moveDistance of all circles?)

Comment: If you mean with with (circle.x,circle.y) the center of the circle, than I disagree. The direction you want to move is in most cases not exactly the opposite direction to the direction to the center of a circle.

Comment: I updated my comment above a bit. Ah now I understand what you mean. You have a line into the direction in which the object should move. The farest point that lies on the line and is inside all the circles is the farest point to which the object can move? How would you efficiently implement that?

Comment: Google can help. e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228841/how-do-i-calculate-the-intersections-of-a-straight-line-and-a-circle might be useful.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it. I know how to calculate the intersection of a line and a circle. But I'm not sure how to find the farest point that lies inside all the radiuses...? At the moment I think it is only possible by walking along the line (+=small step) until a point is reached that lies outside...?

Comment: Calculate the intersection of line with all circles and take the intersection nearest to the object.

Comment: thank you for getting back :)! That is to get to know if a rope is stretched. But lets say we have a direction vector(3/5), how can we find out how far the object can go into that direction until a/some ropes are stretched? I havent found a solution without iterating over the line...